# How to support multiple customers within application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, database-design

I have previously developed MVC applications that are for a specific implementation, with multiple users all using the same data. I am now looking at developing an application which I intend to sell multiple hosted copies of. For example, say I developed an event management application where a company could sign-up, add their events, create users etc. How do I host multiple instances of this application for the different customers? The methods I can see are:

1) For each new customer create a new website/database instance with Azure and upload the application. The disadvantage being the hosting costs would soon build up.

2) Host all the clients in the same application and edit each data query I make to add a WHERE clause that checks for the companies ID on each table.

3) Use views/synonyms on the database so the user only see's their own data.

What is the best way of achieving this? Is there a better method I haven't thought of? Does MVC have something already built in that can handle this?

Comment: Go with 2, it's easiest and best (win/win).

Comment: MVC doesn't have anything built in but how you implement depends on your requirement. Do you want subdomains, ie client1.myapp.com, client2.myapp.com or just distinct logins?

Comment: Ah, thats a shame there is nothing built in. I guess in an ideal world subdomains would be best.

Comment: It is not that difficult to do though, I have done it before. Here is a pretty good sample http://www.dennisonpro.info/simple-multitenancy-with-asp-net-mvc-4/

Comment: Thanks Craig - good link. What do you feel is the biggest disadvantage to this approach?

Comment: The only disadvantage I think is if there is some legal requirement to have separate databases per client.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed one application in MVC for the same scenario.
We have used **SMO (Server Management Object)** for create a new user for my application.

Actual Scenario like this:
1) Signal application for multiple user with different database.
2) Application creates databases on demand as per creating new clients (Using SMO).
3) Database connection string change at runtime when user login in our application.

I think this information is enough for developer signal application with multiple database,

I hope this is useful for you.

Thanks,
Nikunj B. Balar